# Consul multiple client

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, consul

I am new at the consul. So, I have multiple client instances running and have a java application.
To connect to the client I have given IP of one of the clients. I believe this wrong. Should I give the load balancer IP tat connect to the client or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Consul operates as a distributed system, and is designed for client agents to serve as the primary access point for applications which need to interface with Consul's DNS or HTTP APIs.

Consul clients should be deployed on every node/server in your environment. Applications which are running on a given server should send HTTP/DNS queries to the Consul agent which is running on the same server. This is typically achieved by configuring the Consul agent to listen on localhost (via the [`-client`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_client)/[`client_addr`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#client_addr) option), and configuring your applications to connect to Consul over the same address.